# Why does my 20" iMac running Snow Leopard suffer from very slow wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard, imac

3 different Windows machines on the same wireless from a position 2' from the aforementioned iMac are snappy. All machines using DHCP, and are using the same DNS servers, so it doesn't seem likely to be a DNS issue. Wireless router is a band new (3 weeks old) Belkin N300 - we had the same problem with an older Linksys device and upgraded to se if we could get better speed.

The displayed behavior is generally that the progress bar for the page load proceeds to half or most of the way complete and then the page load seems to stall. Wireless signal indicator stays full, so it doesn't look like the connection is dropping.

Oh, I saw [Wireless internet became extremely slow on my 27" IMac](https://superuser.com/questions/132082/wireless-internet-became-extremely-slow-on-my-27-imac); the problem on our machine doesn't seem to resolve when the machine's been off for a period of time, either - it's almost always slow...

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this. Help?!

**UPDATE**

results of router ping:

```
ping -c 10 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.411 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.092 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.238 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.128 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.189 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.420 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.928 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.515 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=1.459 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=1.309 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.928/1.269/1.515/0.178 ms
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is isolate the issue to connectivity vs. something on the iMac itself.  Try using a wired ethernet connection to the router, and internet-sharing via ethernet from one of the other WiFi-connected machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would try "pinging" your router from a terminal window:

```
ping routerip -c 10
```

If any of the packets take more than 30ms, or if there are any lost/dropped packets, then you know that it's an adapter hardware/software issue, rather than your web browser.

Apart from that, I would try connecting with a cable to see if you still have the problem. Obviously, that is not a fix - but it might help!

I would also try switching from "N" mode to "G" mode on your router. It seems... illogical, but i know that some people having wireless problems with the macbook pro managed to at least reduce the issue by switching to wireless G. You could even disable the DNS/DHCP functionality of your old router and use it as G-Only access point so that your other computers can use Wireless N.

Comment: ping results added above, which look a little slow to me, but I don't have my Windows laptop handy at them moment - I'll try the wireless G switch as well

Answer (score 0):

i would also suggest that you try running your iMac by itself on the network, double check all your internet settings. also try using the diagnostic function which you can find in system prefs-network then select "AirPort" on the left and click "Assist me..." you will then be prompted and there will be a "diagnostics..." button